# How to find if a string match one found in an array?

Tags: c++, arrays, string

What would be the most efficient way to compare a known string against and array of strings in order to see if the given string matches any in the array?

For example: You have

```
string String1 = "ID5";
string String2 = "ID7";
```

You want to see if either of them are contained in the following

```
string List[5] = {"ID1", "ID7", "ID10", "ID34", "ID62"}
```

So that you would be able to do this

```
 if(#STRINGMATCHES) {
    // Do one thing
 }
 else {
    // Do another
 }
```

Comment: Do you only need to perform this once or you need to do it for a lot of known strings?

Comment: @izomorphius The `if...else` is within a `for` loop and it is comparing a single string that changes each time the function is looped, against a static array.

Answer (score 2):

By using **[std::find](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/find/)**

```
std::find(List, List+5, String1)
```

Comment: OP wants to check two strings (String1 and String2), in that case wouldn't it be better to use a `for` loop with `*iter == String1 || *iter == String2` ?

Comment: @Naveen: If the requirement is to compare two strings then [std::find_if()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/find_if/) would serve the purpose.

Comment: @Als What's wrong with `std::find_first_of`?  It seems to do exactly what he wants.

Comment: std::find_first_of will succeed with a partial match:

Notice that unlike member find_first_of, whenever more than one character is being searched for, it is not enough that just one of these characters match, but the entire sequence must match.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to perform this search operation a lot of times here is what I propose - hash all the strings using some hash function and then create a new array containing the sorted hashes. Then when you need to check if a string is contained in the array do a binary_search of its hash in the sorted array. This will be way more efficient then doing just std::find as proposed by als but depend on the fact you will need to perform the search operation enough times so that the speed gain makes up for the sorting overhead.

Comment: If the search list is very large, some sort of hash table could be appropriate (and `std::unordered_set`, for example).  In my experience, the break even point, where something like `std::unordered_set` becomes faster than a binary search on an `std::vector`, is in the thousands of elements, however; for smaller sets, the sorted vector is faster.

Comment: I am not talking about using unordered_set. I propose to use hashes to make comparison between strings constant instead of linear with respect to their lengths. Please note I still propose to use binary_search but on the hashes instead of the strings themselves. This will speed up the search significantly especially for long strings.

Comment: You still need the comparison after the hashes compare equal, but hashes will speed up the detection of mismatches.  In the end, it depends a lot on the length of the tables.  For smaller search tables, you can do the lookup in less time than it would take to calculate the hash code to begin with.

Comment: Yes you need to do explicit comparison in case a match is found to avoid collision errors. Still you need to do only one full comparison instead of comparing on each iteration of the binary search.

Comment: Yes, but the comparison will often only involve the first character, or the first couple of characters.  No more expensive than comparing the hash codes, and you don't pay the price of calculating the hash code.  All this really shows is that when it comes to performance, a lot depends on the data set.  In large sets of data with URLs (where the strings tend to start with identical characters), the hash can be a distinct win.  For small sets of random data, it will probably be a loss.  In the end, if performance is an issue, you have to try many solutions, and measure each.

Answer (score 1):

If the array is sorted you can use [`std::binary_search()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/binary_search):

```
std::string List[] = { "ID1", "ID10", "ID7", "ID34", "ID62" };
if (std::binary_search(std::begin(List), std::end(List), "ID7"))
{
    std::cout << "found string\n";
}
```

If not, the use [`std::find()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) (as already stated by Als).

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution would be to put the strings you're looking for
into an array and use `std::find_first_of`:

```
std::string targetList[] = { "ID5", "ID7" };
std::string searchList[] = { "ID1", "ID2", "ID3", "ID4", "ID5" };

if ( std::find_first_of( begin( searchList ), end( searchList ),
                         begin( targetList ), end( targetList ) )
        != end( targetList ) ) {
    //  found...
} else {
    //  not found...
}
```

This is not necessarily the most efficient solution, because 
`find_first_of` makes no assumtions concerning the data.  If the search
list is very large and doesn't change, for example, and the target list
only contains a few elements, it might be more efficient to sort the
search list, and do a binary search for each element in the target list.

Answer (score 0):

I have an idea.

first, we should make List sorted.just as hmjd describing.

when comparing two strings, we can record some information.

For example,

table two dimenssion array dif records the index where two strings differs.

```
string[2] = {"abc","abd"}
list[5] = {"aab","abb","abc","bcd","ef"}
```

```
dif[0][0] = 1 ("abc" and "aab" differ at index 1) 
dif[0][1] = 2 ("abc" and "abb" differ at index 2) 
dif[0][2] = -1 ("abc" and "abc" are same, so we use -1 to represent two strings are same) 
dif[0][3] = 0 ("abc" and "bcd" differ at index 0) 
dif[0][4] = 0 ("abc" and "eg" differ at index 0)
```

when we need to compare a new string to the strings in list.We first find the most similar string in the strings that have been compared. eg, "abd" is a string needed to judge. We find "abc". "abd" and "abc" differ at index 2. So ,when we compare "adb" and the strings in list, we needn't to compare the strings that differ "abc" in index before 2. eg, we needn't to compare "abd" and "ef",because "abd" differs "abc" at index 2 while "abc" differ "ef" at index 0.

My idea is very rough and has many details to be considered. I think it is useful,especially in large scale problem.